# One sided limits that equal infinity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$\lim_\limits{x \to -8^+}    \frac{3x}{2x+16}$

How would this limit equal to negative infinity I wanted to see how it's done

Comment: the   $\lim_{x \to 8+} \frac{3x}{2x+16} = \frac{3}{4}$ not $\infty$ as you claim in your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to -8^{+}} \frac{3x}{2x+16}=\frac{3(-8)}{2(-8)+16}=-\infty$$

because of the fact that the numerator is negative.

In general, it holds that:

$$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} \frac{b}{x-a}=+\infty, \text{ when } b>0$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} \frac{b}{x-a}=-\infty, \text{ when } b<0$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you want
$x \to -8$
or
$2x-16$
so that
the denominator
goes to zero.
In what you have written,
there is no problem as
$x \to 8$.

If
$x \to -8^+$,
then
$x = -8+c$
where $c > 0$
and $c \to 0^+$.
Then
$\frac{3x}{2x+16}
=\frac{3(-8+c)}{2(-8+c)+16}
=\frac{-24+3c}{2c}
$.

As $c \to 0$,
if
$0 < c < 1$,
$-24+3c < -21$
and $2c > 0$
so that,
since
$2c \to 0$,
$\frac{-24+3c}{2c}
< 0$
and
$\frac{-24+3c}{2c}
\to -\infty$
as
$c \to 0$.